# Bash rows to column

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep, transpose

I know how to transpose rows in a file to columns, but I want to append the lines of the bottom half of a file to the lines to the upper half.

Like:

```
A1
A2
A3
B1
B2
B3
```

to

```
A1 | B1
A2 | B2
A3 | B3
```

the list comes from two `grep`s. I append the first `grep` with the second one. The two `grep`s have the same amount of hits.

I want to do this within a bash script.

Comment: Try to give more context on your `grep`s, etc, so that we can provide better answers. Also, what did you try so far?

Answer (score 2):

What about combining `head` and `tail` together with `paste`?

```
paste -d'|' <(head -3 file) <(tail -3 file)
```

It returns:

```
A1|B1
A2|B2
A3|B3
```

`paste` merges lines of files. If we provide different lines from the same file... that's all!

As it is a matter of getting `head` from the half of the lines and `tail` from the rest, this is a more generic way:

```
paste -d'|' <(head -n $(($(wc -l <file)/2)) file) 
            <(tail -n $(($(wc -l <file)/2)) file)
```

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for the [`pr`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/pr.1.html) tool:

```
printf "%s\n" {A,B}{1,2,3}   |   pr -2 -T -s" | "
```

```
A1 | B1
A2 | B2
A3 | B3
```

Comment: On Solaris: `pr -2 -T -s" | "` -> `pr: illegal option -- T` and `pr -2 -s" | "` -> `pr: illegal option -- |`. Is this GNU `pr` or something?

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk '{a[NR]=$0} END{ m=NR/2; for (i=1;i<=m;i++) print a[i] " | " a[i+m]}' file
A1 | B1
A2 | B2
A3 | B3
```

Answer (score 1):

Just as an alternative:

```
awk 'BEGIN{c=0}
     {a[c++] = $1}
     END { for (i = 0; i < c/2; i++) print a[i] " " a[i+c/2]}'
```

This assumes you have an even number of lines as input.